# Existing iOS form framework

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, xlform

Hello I am building forms over and over in iPhone and iPad apps:

- Custom UITableViewCells for labels with input
- Localization for labels, placeholder text and section headers
- Validation that marks the cells red  or something and does not allow "Submit" if form is incomplete
- Clicking in the cell activates the editable text box
- Next / previous buttons
- Reliable across devices, orientations, iOS versions

I can't imagine I'm the only one doing this. Is there a *mature* framework or something that can drop in and use? Could you please comment on how you use this library with designs other than vanilla UITableViews with your own colors etc.?

Comment: Started looking at https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog

Comment: The ideal solution would be free / GitHub

Comment: @FullDescent I ended up writing another (still private) lib of my own based on lessons learned form first attempt  - will publish source ASAP

Comment: @JasperBlues thanks for the help. I have been doing this custom for too long and would like something more modular

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Take a look at IBAForms - an open source project from from Itty Bitty Apps. I haven't used it yet myself, however I believe it does most of what you want, except for validation. Here is the github page: [IBA Forms](https://github.com/ittybittydude/IBAForms)

It hasn't been maintained in a while, but if you're looking for a forms library - it's mature and works. At the very least, it could be the starting point for something you take further.

- Update: There is also Chris Miles' [EZForm](https://github.com/chrismiles/EZForm) library, which is very nice.
- Update #2: Have also started checking out [QuickDialog](https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog), which seems to be very popular.
- **Update #3: Nick Lockwood has created one called [FXForms](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms)**
- Update #4: Martin Barreto has created one called [XLForm](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm)

Comment: FXForms is the nicest of all the form frameworks I have seen so far. IMHO

Comment: @neoneye - emphasized it in bold text.

Comment: Thanks, mate! Very useful. I'm having a little problem with the FXForms when on the gender form (beats me), so I moved on to QuickDialog and it looks pretty good. Cheers.

Comment: @FelipeGringo I've got my own private forms lib at the moment (abandoned iBureaucrat). Its fairly low level, and so very flexible to reskin, customize, layout, etc. . . perhaps I'll post it up.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this list. I tried QuickDialog and FXForms... FXForms is really great!

Comment: But XLForm seems very powerful too. Maybe I'll give it a try, since I need dynamic forms.

Comment: @JasperBlues Eureka is the sucessor of XLForms, you may want to add it to the list https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka I've been using it and it's quite good.

Comment: @TiagoLira Feel free to edit. Remove any obsolete ones, add new ones, etc.

Comment: I have tried various form frameworks and eventually ended up making my own SwiftyFORM, https://github.com/neoneye/SwiftyFORM

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as an answer, but i use [Sensible Cocoa - Sensible TableView (STV)](http://sensiblecocoa.com/) for this purpose a lot. It's not a "forms" framework (on top of UITableView) as such, but it can be used for this purpose in a very flexible way. It still requires some coding to build a full-fledged form but the UITableView/UITableViewController boilerplate code is reduced to a minimum. Unfortunately the developers bumped the price tag quite high with version 3.0, so i'm actually looking for a STV replacement right now. (I'd stick with STV if it wasn't for the price!)

Comment: I also use STV and while it has a bit of a learning curve, it's a nice framework that is very extensible.  They do charge for the full version, but they have a lite version that is available as a static framework and it works nicely with your own object models, dictionaries, strings and NSUserDefaults.  If you pay, you get core data and web services as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of anything that combines all those features, but I recently open-sourced my validation library [PMValidation](https://github.com/poetmountain/PMValidation) on github, which I used developing the iPhone app [Imprints](https://itunes.apple.com/app/imprints/id577195548?mt=8). PMValidation comes with many basic types suitable for validating forms, and in fact that's what I originally built it for.

Using the PMValidationManager class you can easily listen to UITextViews or UITextFields, and update whatever graphical widgets you want via notifications. It's very modular and easily extendable, should you have more unique needs. It's under the MIT license.