# UiTableView as Navigation method in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

please have a look at the attached image. I would like to build such a view to add some data to my app. Is the view shown in the image a UiTableView with custom cells? Is there a tutarial showing how to use an UiTableView for form elements (using siwft)?
Thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: This is a **Grouped UITableView**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you look for a third party library that has already implemented what you want.  If they're Objective-C you can still use them from Swift through the bridging header.

See this question for some ideas:
[Existing iOS form framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552422/existing-ios-form-framework)